# OCI Connect Issue at Windows Server 2012 with PHP Version 5.6.14

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface, php-5.6

[OCI Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646007/oci-connect-connection-failed)

Based upon the above, it states that one should avoid OCI connection on Windows. Have someone configured it on Windows? I have gone through all other threads, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257894/call-to-undefined-function-oci-connect-php-oci8-12c-dll-windows-8-1-php5-6-6) and [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1051752), using Windows Server 2012 with PHP 5.6 and Oracle 11g but still having issue:

> Call to undefined function oci_connect()

I have **set the path**: `c:/instantclient_12_1`

**Under `php.ini`, one can see:**

;extension=php_oci8.dll
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll

while under **/php/ext**

there is only file: `php_oci8_12c.dll`

**This is the output of phpinfo() to show configure command:**

```
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without- pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
```

What is the reason of an error `undefined function oci_connect()`?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might want to ask this on Serverfault.com (SO's sister site) which is more suited to this kind of question.

Comment: PHP/OCI is no problem on Windows; I have it running on several production servers. You've already linked to [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29515269/3775731), which is about as comprehensive as you'll find on this topic. Have you checked the `php_errors.log` file for startup errors?

Comment: And check the output of `where oci*` at the command line to confirm the system path contains the correct reference to your oci client files.

Comment: I have linked your answer in my post

Comment: extension=php_oci8_12c.dll is not in php.ini file. If copy it then it shows error: program cant start because php5.dll is missing

Comment: I have also followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566822/xampp-missing-php-eaccelerator-ts-dll but no success.

Comment: `php5.dll is missing` most likely means that you are trying to use a non-thread safe file with a thread safe build of PHP. Try downloading the correct file from [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.0.8/windows).

Comment: The issue get resolved after placing the file php_oci8_11g.dll in /php/ext folder

Comment: Thanks to  @timclutton

Answer (score 0):

Try using following:

```
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll
```

in your php.ini, in my case (Windows Server 2008, PHP 5.6) that helped.

Comment: The issue get resolved after placing the file php_oci8_11g.dll in /php/ext folder