# can not connect to oracle database using PHP 5.6.14 - OCI Connect issue

Tags: php, oracle, apache, xampp, oci8

i want to connect into my oracle database, i use xampp 5.6.14, i already uncomment the extension :

```
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
```

when i check in php.ini file, it's only have extension

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
```

but in the extension directory, extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext" , this dll is saved as

```
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll
```

is there any mistake from xampp with this version ? any solution for this case ? thank you ..

Comment: have you already install Oracle Instant Client?
if not you can download [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

Comment: I assume you are using windows and trying to connect to Oracle 11g? Please install oracle instant client according to your OS platform. You can download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html, The instant client path should be added to your system path variables.

Comment: yes. hmmm ... previously i use xampp 1.6.4, and its work fine. now, i update my xampp into 5.6.14. and can not connect into database. is there any different instant client between xampp 1.6.4 and 5.6.14 ?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893407/oci-connect-issue-at-windows-server-2012-with-php-version-5-6-14 entirely with relevant links and you will find solution exactly

Comment: I think the older files are also working with newer client/server versions, did you try php_oci8_11g.dll `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34494636/2125924

Comment: @PradeepSanjaya Do I need to install oracle instant client, while I was install oracle database on the same machine with xampp?

Answer (score 3):

Un-comment this line only:

`;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll` ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client

then download this file from [OCI files](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.0.8/php_oci8-2.0.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip)

and place missing files in /php/ext folder.

*Hope instant client 12.1 already installed and configured.*

Comment: i already uncomment the extension, extension=php_oci8.dll; (i used oracle db 10g) and add php_oci8.dll in dir C:\xampp\php\ext , but i got an error when i started the apache. the error said "The procedure entry point php_checkuid could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll."

Comment: Uncomment this: extension=php_oci8_11g.dll only

Comment: i use oracle db 10g not 11g, btw, link that you give it to me, can not open

Comment: There seem to be mismatch. See this article: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/connect-wamp-server-to-oracle-with-php-php_oci8_11g-dll